# Logout in Mozilla and chrome not working

Tags: 2013, javascript

I have configured fba in my site using thinktecture. When I click sign out or sign in as different user, sharepoint redirects me to following page:

```
/_login/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3floginasanotheruser%3dtrue%26Source%3d&loginasanotheruser=true&Source=
```

If I select windows authentication in dropdown, it redirect me to user homepage without prompting authentication dialogue.

For IE I got the solution like this:

```
document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");
```

but it's not working in chrome and mozilla. I have searched many sites on google but nothing help much.

I have tried following patch too.But nothing work for chrome and firefox.

Open Internet Explorer -> Tools - Internet options - > Local intranet Zone - > user Authentication ; Select - prompt For user name and password.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can not log out from SharePoint just setting a logout URL to your browser.
I dug it a lot after that I found there is a session cookie which name is **"FedAuth"** is responsible for user logout as soon as you delete that cookie it will log out your session. it is a serverside session cookie so you can't find it out in document.cookie. you need to call a REST API to delete this cookie in server side.
this approach I was following in Sharepoint on-Premise. but Sharepoint online I think it is not possible. or may be possible if you are able to delete **"FedAuth"** cookie.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try following code samples.Any one should work:

**1)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function _spBodyOnLoad() {
    var PreviousPage = document.referrer.split('/')[3];      
    if (PreviousPage == "adfs") {
        var searchString = getQueryStringParameter('site');
        PreviousPage=searchString;
        }
    var browserName = navigator.appName.toLowerCase();
    if (browserName.indexOf("internet explorer") != -1) {
        document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");
        location.replace("/ABCD/SitePages/Page.aspx?site=" + PreviousPage);
        }
        else {
            var LogOutUrl = "https://ABCD/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0";
            location.replace(LogOutUrl);         
    }          
} 

function getQueryStringParameter(paramName) { 
    var searchString = window.location.search.substring(1); 
    var i; 
    var val; 
    var params = searchString.split("&"); 
    for (i = 0; i < params.length; i++) { 
        val = params[i].split("="); 
        if (val[0] == paramName) { 
            return val[1]; 
        } 
    }

    return null; 
}
```

**2)**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
try{
  var agt=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  if (agt.indexOf("msie") != -1) {
    // IE clear HTTP Authentication
    document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");
  }
  else {
    // Let's create an xmlhttp object
    var xmlhttp = createXMLObject();
    // Let's get the force page to logout for mozilla
    xmlhttp.open("GET",".force_logout_offer_login_mozilla",true,"logout","logout");
    // Let's send the request to the server
    xmlhttp.send("");
    // Let's abort the request
    xmlhttp.abort();
  }
  // Let's redirect the user to the main webpage
  window.location = "/rest/";
} catch(e) {
// There was an error
alert("there was an error");
}

function createXMLObject() {
    try {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        // code for IE
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        xmlhttp=false
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you tell me where should i place this code as i do not have custom sign out. we are using SharePoint given sign out .

Comment: Try adding this is master page

Comment: I have implemented both the scripts. The first one does not give any result. When i put the second script, my site goes into an infinity loop. The page getting refresh.

Comment: Did you try and debug the script? Because i am using the same script and is working fine.

Comment: It executes without error but go in to loop. I can't figure it out.